# Error on list page - Search results only

Tags: magento-1.8, product-list, search

Hi I am getting an error when I try and pull back review stars from Feefo. I have the following code in my list.phtml which works fine when browsing through products. However on the search results page it errors!

```
<?php echo $this->getChild('feefo_category_product_logo')->setProduct($_product)->toHtml(); ?>
Fatal Error:  Call to a member function setProduct() on a non-object in "/path/list.phtml" on line 98
```

Does anyone have any idea why it would throw up this error on the search page and not on a category listing page?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set child "feefo_category_product_logo" for the catalog search layout also.

Add child in `search_result_list` reference. you can add it in `catalogsearch.xml` or `local.xml` of your theme.

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
  <reference name="search_result_list">
    <!-- add child here-->
  </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks! I have found the location I need to add the child, can you provide an example of how the <!-- add child here --> should be formatted?

Comment: search "feefo_category_product_logo" word in your theme or find it in catalog.xml or local.xml. you will need to copy same xml code and paste as I shown above in my answer.